# How to create a SPLIT_STRING function in Db2

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to write a db2 function, below is the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING (INPUT VARCHAR(8000), DELIMITER 
CHAR(1) DEFAULT ',')
RETURNS TABLE (str VARCHAR(8000))
SPECIFIC SPLIT_STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN ATOMIC
 DECLARE @MSG VARCHAR(30)
 SET @MSG ='INVALID INPUT'
 IF (INPUT IS NULL) THEN RETURN @MSG
ELSE
 RETURN
 WITH R1 (str, REMAINDER) AS
 (SELECT SUBSTR(INPUT, 1, LOCATE(DELIMITER, INPUT) -1) AS str,
    SUBSTR(INPUT, LOCATE(DELIMITER, INPUT) +1 , LENGTH(INPUT)) 
 REMAINDER FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

UNION ALL
SELECT SUBSTR(REMAINDER, 1, LOCATE(DELIMITER, REMAINDER)-1) AS str,
   SUBSTR(REMAINDER, LOCATE(DELIMITER, REMAINDER)+1, LENGTH(REMAINDER)) 
REMAINDER  FROM R1
WHERE LOCATE(DELIMITER, REMAINDER) > 0

UNION ALL
SELECT SUBSTR(REMAINDER, LOCATE(DELIMITER, REMAINDER)+1, 
LENGTH(REMAINDER)) AS str,'' AS REMAINDER  FROM R1 WHERE REMAINDER <> ''
AND LOCATE(DELIMITER, REMAINDER) = 0

)SELECT str FROM R1
END IF
END;
```

If I remove the IF condition which am using for Input parameter validation function gets created fine else getting below error.

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was 
not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:SQL0104N  An unexpected token "SET" was found following "RE @MSG VARCHAR(30) ".  Expected tokens may include:  <SQL_variable_declarations>".  LINE NUMBER=8.  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Comment: Are you sure DB2 uses `@` to prefix a variable? (Plus you don't really need that "variable". A simple return 'Invalid input'` would work just as well as you don't use `msg` anywhere else.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  initially i tried without variable MSG, just like `if (INPUT is null) THEN Return 'Invalid Input'` . Since that also throws error like below  
   `DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "ELSE" was found following "URN 'Invalid Input' 
".  Expected tokens may include:  "<delim_semicolon>".  LINE NUMBER=9.  
SQLSTATE=42601` i added that MSG variable

Comment: How do you create the function, from a tool or reading from a file? What is the statement terminator? Is Oracle compatibility on?

Comment: @data_henrik Am trying to execute the file using db2 command line like `db2 -tvf function.sql` , if i remove the if condition the function creation works fine.

Comment: Don't the declare and set need to be terminated?

Comment: @data_henrik tried terminating them using `;` but nothing changed still the same error. So i removed the Declare variable part and just tried with `if (INPUT is null) THEN Return 'Invalid Input'` but still error

Comment: Too many errors... 1. [RETURN](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004237.html): `In an SQL table or row function using a compound SQL (inlined) statement, the only RETURN statement allowed is the one at the end of the compound statement. (SQLSTATE 429BD)` 2. Every statement inside the routine must be followed by ';' and the statement separator must be changed from default ';' to, let's say, '/' 3. If you really want to implement a string splitter, and this is not just a training, there is a better and much shorter alternative.

Comment: Try with e.g. `db2 -td/ -f` and use / as your statement delimiter in your code

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Yes my main intention is to get the string split what is that, alternate.  And i can't change the default delimiter because for deployment we use the tool which default uses ; , if change then it will break other scripts

Comment: @AdarshHDDev: As for statement delimiter: I'm curious what you would do if you had to implement a routine/trigger with a compound statement with such a 'tool' which can't change the default delimiter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String splitter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING (INPUT VARCHAR(8000), DELIMITER CHAR(1) DEFAULT ',')
RETURNS TABLE (str VARCHAR(8000))
SPECIFIC SPLIT_STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
return
select str
from xmltable('for $id in tokenize($s, $p) return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
passing 
  --INPUT as "s"
  COALESCE(INPUT, CAST(RAISE_ERROR('70001', 'INVALID INPUT') AS VARCHAR(8000))) as "s"
, DELIMITER as "p"
columns 
  str varchar(8000) path '.'
) t;
```

Comment: Thanks for this but if still need to validate the input value then this will also start giving me error if i add the if condition as i did above.

Comment: Did I get it right, that your necessarily have to return a result set with a single 'INVALID INPUT' string (which looks quite strange) an not to raise a error in case of NULL input?

Comment: I just need valid on null input it can be return or raiserror

Comment: `passing 
  COALESCE(INPUT, CAST(RAISE_ERROR('70001', 'INVALID INPUT') AS VARCHAR(8000))) as "s"`

Comment: thanks , but its not printing the error message which is passed in RAISE_ERROR it is throwing the default system message `No authorized routine named "SPLIT_STRING" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.22.29 
`

Comment: @AdarshHDDev You probably didn't understand what I proposed. I changed the 'CREATE FUNCTION' definition above.